# How to add a new line in Yii2 Data Confirm

Tags: php, yii2, confirm-dialog

I have a button using the following code in my view...

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete Summary', [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Really long message.<new line>Line 2<new line>Line 3?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
```

I want to make the eventual confirmation dialog show my text on different lines, but none of the common notations such as `\n`, `<br>`, nor `&#10;&#13;` work. I also tried putting `\\n` instead of `\n`, still it did not work.

How can I make the different parts of my confirmation show on a different line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write as with the newline

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete Summary', [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Really long message.
            Line 2
            Line 3?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]) ;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` is you define string using `"` quotes:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete Summary', [
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => "Really long message.\nLine 2\nLine 3?",
        'method' => 'post',
    ],
]) ?>
```

You can also split it into multiple lines to improve readability:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete Summary', [
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => "Really long message."
            . "\nLine 2"
            . "\nLine 3?",
        'method' => 'post',
    ],
]) ?>
```